# Can the DocSets installed by Xcode be moved to an external disk?

Tags: xcode, symlink, documentation

While attempting to clean up my Air's SSD, the estimable [DaisyDisk](http://www.daisydiskapp.com) showed me that 4 GB is being eaten up by Xcode DocSets. I like keeping my friends close and my SDK documentation closer, so I'd be happiest if I could maintain a copy of these DocSets on an external disk, so they're available offline but not cluttering my SSD.

The DocSets currently exist at `~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets`. Is it possible to move the `.docset` files themselves to a different location (perhaps symlinking to them) without breaking Xcode's doc viewer?

Answer (score 3):

In Terminal, run

```
mv ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets /Volumes/HDNAME
ln -s /Volumes/HDNAME/DocSets ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
```

This may take a few minutes to complete.